# How to measure accuracy of time series model based on RMSE?

Tags: python, lstm, prediction, forecasting

I'm developing a LSTM forecasting model for demand of organization based on historical data!
I got Root Mean Square Error (RMSE)= 0.12 and 0.15 train and test score respectively.

My question is how to calculate accuracy of my model based on the above RMSE values?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/accuracy-error-rate) accuracy is a technical term used in Machine Learning and it is used for classification, your model is probably doing regression, since the RMSE error is being used.
I suggest using R-squared measure to get a better picture of how correct is your predictions.